# Necessary condition for square integrable functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, mathematics

I'm studying Quantum Mechanics and I came across this which I don't quite understand:
For a vector space of functions $f(x)$ to be square integrable (i.e $\int{|f(x)|^2dx < \infty)}$, the necessary condition is $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x) \to 0$. Can someone help me understand why that must be the case? I sort of understand that it must not blow up at the infinities but can a (continuous or piece-wise continuous) function have a non-zero finite value at the infinities and still be square integrable?