# Sufficient condition for square integrability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

1. The necessary condition for $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi(x)|^2dx$ to be integrable is that $\psi(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$. But this is not the sufficient condition. For example, $\delta(x)$ vanishes as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$, but it is not square-integrable. What is the sufficient criterion for $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi(x)|^2dx$ to converge?
2. In the previous question $\psi(x)$ was an arbitrary function. If now $\psi(x,t)$ be an arbitrary solution (not necessarily a stationary state) of the time-dependent Schrodinger equation what is the sufficiency condition for $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi(x,t)|^2dx$ to be finite?
3. Does this conditions remain valid in three-dimensions?

**EDIT**: Can we have a *continuous* function $\psi(x)$ which does not go to zero as $x\rightarrow \pm\infty$ and yet the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\psi(x)|^2dx$ converges?

Comment: This is a math question.  Consider Math SE

Comment: Also, see this. As it turns out, going to zero isn't even necessary http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75527/

Comment: Yeah, going to zero is not necessary. A function that is $e^{-x^2}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ and $1$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ is perfectly square-integrable wrt Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @TylerHG If this is a mathematical question then various theorems we prove in quantum mechanics also belong to mathematics.

Comment: Concerning 2, a sufficient condition for a solution of the Schrödinger equation to be in $L^2$, is that it is in $L^2$ at some $t\in\mathbb{R}$. However this is sort of tautological: in fact we define the solution of Schrödinger's equation to be unitary, i.e. to preserve the $L^2$ norm. In principle, there can be non-unitary solutions of the Schrödinger equations in some function space.

Comment: Qmechanic gives a smooth counterexample to the condition being necessary [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/75705/50583). I'm not sure what your question is - in general, there is no better characterization of square-integrable functions other than them being, well, square-integrable. Also, $\delta(x)$ doesn't "vanish" as $x\to \pm\infty$, that doesn't make sense to begin with - the Dirac delta is not a function.

Comment: Also, consider replacing "the necessary condition" by "a necessary condition". There never is a unique necessary (or sufficient) condition.